# How to link mpi4py against intelmpi

Tags: pip, openmpi, mpi4py, intel-mpi

I would like to install mpi4py against intelmpi and this is exactly what i see when i do a module list.

however mpi4py.get_config() shows openmpi after these trials:

```
pip install mpi4py
env MPICC=/share/apps/intel/2017u4/impi/2017.3.196/intel64/bin/mpicc pip install mpi4py
```

I don't have permissions to remove openmpi. how do I flush it out so that mpi4py gets the right one?

Comment: this worked: env MPICC=/share/apps/intel/2017u4/impi/2017.3.196/intel64/bin/mpicc pip install https://bitbucket.org/mpi4py/mpi4py/downloads/mpi4py-3.0.0.tar.gz

Answer (score 0):

[Installation instructions](https://pypi.org/project/mpi4py/#install) say `mpicc` should be in `$PATH` so try

```
env PATH=/share/apps/intel/2017u4/impi/2017.3.196/intel64/bin:$PATH pip install mpi4py
```